# struggling with REACT (setState())

Tags: reactjs, class, state, jsx

New to REACT, the problem is simple, there are three "color" buttons. When one is clicked, the h1 tag gets changed to the to the buttons color. The h1's default is black.

```
const root = document.getElementById("root");


class ChangeColors extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { color: "black" };
  }
  render() {
    const styleChange = () => {
      this.setState({ color: this.state.color })
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 style={style}>Change My Colour!</h1>
        <p>
          <button onClick={this.styleChange} style={color: 
  red}>Red</button>
          <button onClick={this.styleChange} style={color: 
    blue}>Blue</button>
          <button onClick={this.styleChange} style={color: 
   green}>Green</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ChangeColors />, root);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of syntaxe errors in your code, but here is a fixed version : https://codesandbox.io/s/62row8358z

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I will go over what you did so I can understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently when `this.styleChange` is called, it's setting the state to the current color in the state. In order to pass the colour from the button, you need to add it as a parameter:

```
const styleChange = (newColor) => {
  this.setState({ color: newColor })
}
...
<h1 style={{ color: this.state.color }}>Change My Colour!</h1>
<button onClick={() => this.styleChange("red")} style={{ color: "red" }}>Red</button>
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is React, in a auto bound React event handler (method created as an arrow function) `this` is the class instance (of `ChangeColors`), not the element (button) on which the event occured.

The `styleChange` handler must be declared at the class level, not in the render method.

Also style attributes must be written this way `style={{ ...obj }}`. because a non string the jsx value must enclosed by `{}` and the value itself is an object in the case of the style attribute.

And finally the value of the color in the style attribute must be a string, unquoted red blue and green css constant won't work.

```js
const root = document.getElementById("root");


class ChangeColors extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { color: "black" };
  }
  styleChange = (evt) => {
      this.setState({ color: evt.target.style.color })
  }
  render() {
     
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 style={{ color: this.state.color}}>Change My Colour!</h1>
        <p>
          <button onClick={this.styleChange} style={{color: 'red' }}>Red</button>
          <button onClick={this.styleChange} style={{color: 'blue' }}>Blue</button>
          <button onClick={this.styleChange} style={{color: 'green' }}>Green</button>
        </p>
      </div>
   );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ChangeColors />, root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```